# Roots of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

Solve the equation
$$z^3-1=0$$
Show that the roots are represented in an Argand diagram by the vertices of an equilateral triangle.

(EDITED: Thank you for your quick respond)

Comment: **One** root is obvious.

Comment: I know that z=1. Two more

Comment: Synthetic division and use the quadratic formula.

Comment: @copper.hat $$\begin{array}{l}\text{One Root to rule them all}\cr
\text{One Root to find them,}\cr
\text{One Root to bring them all,}\cr
\text{And in the darkness bind them.}\end{array}$$

Comment: @WillJagy Three Roots for the Elven kings, under the sky.

Comment: @WillJagy: There's a ring of truth to that...

Comment: $$ z^3 - 1 = (z-1)(z^2 + z + 1). $$ Same as $$ a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2 + ab + b^2), $$ or $$ a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)(a^2 - ab + b^2), $$

Comment: @Lee: Look for 'symmetries' in the equation. For example, if $z$ solves the equation, for what values of $\theta$ will $e^{i \theta} z$ also solve the equation? You know there are three solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some simple observations:

a) Since $z^3 = 1$, we know $|z^3| = |z|^3 = |1| = 1$.

This implies $|z| = 1$ (since $|z| \in \Bbb R^+_0$). So all of our roots (should they exist) lie on the unit circle in the Argand plane.

b) If $z \neq 1$, then $z$ is a root of $\dfrac{x^3 -1}{x -1} = x^2 + x + 1$. This can be solved via the quadratic equation, if one wishes to.

c) Complex multiplication is *closed* in the unit circle, and corresponds to rotation. Thus we seek points on the unit circle with angle $\theta$ (relative to the positive real axis), such that $3\theta =$ an integer multiple of $2\pi$. There are two such angles in the range: $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$(\rho \exp(i\theta))^3=\rho^3\exp(3i\theta)=\exp(0)$$

so $\rho=1$ and $3\theta\equiv 0 \mod 2\pi$

So $1,\exp\big(i\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\big)$ and $\exp\big(i\dfrac{4\pi}{3}\big)$ are solutions. And there are 3 solutions, so you have all three.

Comment: Be careful.  You should have obtained $3\theta \equiv 0 \pmod{2\pi}$.  The three roots you found do not form an equilateral triangle.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig edited, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$z^{3}=1$, using De Moivre formula we get that $z^{\frac{1}{3}}=|z|^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot [\cos(\frac{\phi + 2 \pi r}{n})+i\sin(\frac{\phi + 2 \pi r}{n})]$, $r \in {0, 1, 2, \ldots n-1}$ $z^{\frac{1}{3}}=cos(\frac{2 \pi r}{3})+i\sin(\frac{2 \pi r}{3})$, where $r \in {0, 1, 2}$.

After this, we can draw  points, corresponding to the roots, using a unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

As a different approach, $z=1$ is a root of $z^3-1$ if and only if $(z-1)$ is a factor of $z^3-1$. Using algebra, you should verify that
\begin{equation}
z^3-1=(z-1)(z^2+z+1).
\end{equation}
Hence, $z^3-1=0$ yields $z-1=0$ (this gives the solution you were already aware of) or $z^2+z+1=0$. The second equation is quadratic and easy to find solutions for. From here, simply plot the roots you found and verify that "connecting the dots" yields an equilateral triangle.